# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I am running my app with Maven. But I get an error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

App uses log4j:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);
        logger.info("Test 1,2,3");
        System.out.println("End of my program");

    }
}
```

pom.xml file includes next dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

How to solve this problem? I checked solutions in google but it doesnt help...

I tried to add implepentation for example slf4j-simple but nothing changed

[errr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilifQ.png)

Comment: Please add the error as text instead of an image so it is easier for others to see it.

Comment: The `slf4j-simple` artifact has a `test` scope, so it is probably not available, when your run your `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution did not need to **test scope** in Slf4j Dependencies because it is probably not available when you run your main method.

```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.30</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.30</version>
           <scope>test</scope>  //Remove the test scope
       </dependency>
```

Then it's working fine without any errors.

Thanks.